# Publish ASP.NET MVC project with Local DB on a server that does not have SQL Server installed on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and I am using a local SQL Server database.

I want to publish that project on an IIS Local server, but this IIS local server does not have SQL Server. The SQL Server is not installed on that local server.

Can I publish project on that server or not?

Comment: If your app needs SQL Server - there **must be** SQL Server available where you publish to - either on that IIS Server itself, or on another server that is reachable from that IIS Server via the network.

Comment: try SQLite, if I remember correctly you just reference the file and you can access the db in visual studio itself.  Otherwise you are looking at docker a solution.

Comment: Docker is one option but unecessary in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can publish your app on your server which SQL Server is not installed on it; but you should have **another server** (at least) which the **SQL Server is installed on that** and set your app **connection string** on that server, so your project will be connected to the DB.

You can do that with **cloud base services**!

But you should be aware of **security issues**.

If you can not install SQL Server on your own server because of **OS**, **low resources**, **maintenance issues** and etc. this solution may be help you.

These two articles from **Microsoft** may be helpful:

1.
[Connecting from Another Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver16)

2.
[Import or link to data in an SQL Server database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-sql-server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e)